# how to run javascript and get result on android

Tags: javascript, android

I used below JSTest class and JSInterface to get javascript result
But "processJsReturnValue" function didn't be called.
What is my mistake?

```
public class JSTest {
  private String jsReturnValue =null;
  private WebView webView;
  public Context mContext;

  private static class JSInterface {
    private JSTest myContext;

    public JSInterface(JSTest context) {
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processReturnValue(String value) {
        myContext.processJsReturnValue(value);
    }
  }

  public JSTest(Context context) {
    super();
    mContext = context;
    webView = new WebView(context);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(this), "androidInterface");
    String jsString = "(function(){"+
          "window.androidInterface.processReturnValue('abc');"+
        "})();";
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+jsString);
  }

  public void processJsReturnValue(String value) {
    Log.e("got it", value);
    jsReturnValue = value;  
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if your `jsString` is changed to: `String jsString = "androidInterface.processReturnValue('abc');";`?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `processJsReturnValue` function is not called? Do you get any errors in the Javascript? Or on the android side?

Comment: To see javascript errors in the java console, easiest way is probably to override the `onConsoleMessage` in the `webview.setWebChromeCLient` function. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebChromeClient(android.webkit.WebChromeClient)

Comment: I'm sure 100% Because That Log doesn't recored. and There is no android error. but I don't know if there is javascript error.

Comment: Thanks I got an javascript error "androidInterface" is not defined.
But I don't know why this error is occurred

Comment: If you override `onPageFinished` in `setWebViewClient` and call your javascript there instead, does it do any difference? Its possible that the 'page' is not loaded yet when you call the androidInterface object. I might be wrong in this tho.

Comment: Also, you might want to set the webview to point to a page, could just do like: `webView.loadData("<html></html>", "text/html", "utf8");` If you do not want to send it to a 'real' page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it from @Jite's help

solution:

```
public JSTest(Context context) {
    super();
    mContext = context;
    webView = new WebView(context);
    // chromeClient = new CustomWebChromeClient();
    //webView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    jsinterface = new JSInterface(this);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsinterface, "androidInterface");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
            Log.e("", "do loading");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.e("", "do loading finished");
            String jsString = "window.androidInterface.processReturnValue('abc');";
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+jsString);


         }
     });
    webView.loadData("<html></html>", "text/html", "utf8");
  }
```